# C++ ignores blanks in a text file using a Stringstream for reading

Tags: c++, stringstream

I try to read several lines from a textfile and want to store the single items in a struct. The code looks like this:

```
std::string line;
struct _DomainTable_ line_of_file;
while (getline(infile_, line))
{
  std:: stringstream linebuffer(line);
  line_of_file.short_ = "";
  line_of_file.long_ = "";
  linebuffer >> line_of_file.id_ >> line_of_file.short_ << line_of_file.long_;
  domain_list_.push_back(line_of_file);
  it_++;
}
```

The single items in my text file are seperated by a blank.
Unfortunately my program ignores the second blank between the second and the thrid column, so that the whole text after the "id_" is stored in "short_".
Perhaps someone knows a better method to read a formatted file (such as scanf in C). I am workimg with C++ builder, and rather I don't want to use C anymore.

best regards and thank you very much 
Andreas Höhenberger

Comment: Please post example input and matching expected result

Comment: this is one line of my file: 2 AZ Asbestzement. result should be: id_ = 2, short = AZ, long = Asbestzement. result is: id_ = 2, short = AZ Asbestzement, long = empty

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you write the input file by hand? I would just like to exclude encoding issues.

Comment: Unrelated: Unlikely to cause you problems, but... `_DomainTable_` is a reserved identifier. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to read a typical line from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. There is a very good solution, which I found here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c/1120224#1120224
```

String handling seems to be tricky under C++ too.